# Terraform: use of closed network connection

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, terraform

I'm using this plugin for terraform: https://github.com/terra-farm/terraform-provider-virtualbox

I just try to install an ubuntu 18.04 box in virtualbox.

This is my `main.tf`

```
resource "virtualbox_vm" "node" {
    count = 2
    name = "${format("node-%02d", count.index+1)}"
    url = "https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/bionic64/versions/20180802.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box"
    image = "./virtualbox-ubuntu.box"
    cpus = 2
    memory = "512 mib",


    network_adapter {
        type = "bridged",
        host_interface = "en0",

    }


}
output "IPAddr" {
    value = "${element(virtualbox_vm.node.*.network_adapter.0.ipv4_address, 1)}"
}
output "IPAddr_2" {
    value = "${element(virtualbox_vm.node.*.network_adapter.0.ipv4_address, 2)}"
}
```

When I perform `terraform apply` it fails with:

```
2018-08-07T22:17:41.256+0200 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-virtualbox: pid-3041-vbm.go:75: executing: VBoxManage showvminfo node-02 --machinereadable
2018-08-07T22:17:41.346+0200 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-virtualbox: pid-3041-vbm.go:75: executing: VBoxManage showvminfo node-01 --machinereadable
2018-08-07T22:17:41.352+0200 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-virtualbox: pid-3041-vbm.go:45: executing: VBoxManage clonehd /Users/name/.terraform/virtualbox/gold/virtualbox-ubuntu/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-configdrive.vmdk /Users/name/.terraform/virtualbox/machine/node-02/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-configdrive.vmdk
2018-08-07T22:17:41.412+0200 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-virtualbox: pid-3041-resource_vm.go:247: [ERROR] Clone *.vdi and *.vmdk to VM folder: exit status 1
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalWriteState
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyProvisioners
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalIf
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalWriteState
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalWriteDiff
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyPost
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyPost, err: 1 error(s) occurred:

* virtualbox_vm.node.1: exit status 1
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: 1 error(s) occurred:

* virtualbox_vm.node.1: exit status 1
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] [walkApply] Exiting eval tree: virtualbox_vm.node[1]
2018-08-07T22:17:41.454+0200 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-virtualbox: pid-3041-vbm.go:45: executing: VBoxManage clonehd /Users/name/.terraform/virtualbox/gold/virtualbox-ubuntu/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-configdrive.vmdk /Users/name/.terraform/virtualbox/machine/node-01/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-configdrive.vmdk
2018-08-07T22:17:41.516+0200 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-virtualbox: pid-3041-resource_vm.go:247: [ERROR] Clone *.vdi and *.vmdk to VM folder: exit status 1
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalWriteState
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyProvisioners
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalIf
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalWriteState
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalWriteDiff
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] root: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyPost
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalApplyPost, err: 1 error(s) occurred:

* virtualbox_vm.node.0: exit status 1
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [ERROR] root: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: 1 error(s) occurred:

* virtualbox_vm.node.0: exit status 1
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] [walkApply] Exiting eval tree: virtualbox_vm.node[0]
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream errored, not walking "output.IPAddr_2"
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream errored, not walking "provider.virtualbox (close)"
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream errored, not walking "output.IPAddr"
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream errored, not walking "meta.count-boundary (count boundary fixup)"
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream errored, not walking "root"
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] Preserving existing state lineage "782abaa9-e567-10d4-1902-6d1223713e6a"
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] Preserving existing state lineage "782abaa9-e567-10d4-1902-6d1223713e6a"
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] Preserving existing state lineage "782abaa9-e567-10d4-1902-6d1223713e6a"
2018/08/07 22:17:41 [TRACE] Preserving existing state lineage "782abaa9-e567-10d4-1902-6d1223713e6a"

2018/08/07 22:17:41 [DEBUG] plugin: waiting for all plugin processes to complete...
Error: Error applying plan:

2 error(s) occurred:

* virtualbox_vm.node[1]: 1 error(s) occurred:

* virtualbox_vm.node.1: exit status 1
* virtualbox_vm.node[0]: 1 error(s) occurred:

* virtualbox_vm.node.0: exit status 1

Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
2018-08-07T22:17:41.522+0200 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-virtualbox: pid-3041-rpc_server.go:48: [ERR] plugin: plugin server: accept unix /var/folders/y4/v8w900l115lbtzylp143pxfr0000gn/T/plugin055999022: use of closed network connection
Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with
any resources that successfully completed. Please address the error
above and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure.
```

What am I doing wrong? the example with an older image seems to work?

Comment: the first error is  `...pid-3041-resource_vm.go:247: [ERROR] Clone *.vdi and *.vmdk to VM folder: exit status 1` isn't it an issue with source availability or target available space ?

Comment: @Tuckbros that's the sort of information I'm looking for. Update the question with an answer and the bounty is yours.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the boxes contain two hard disks, not one. The https://vagrantcloud.com/geerlingguy/boxes/ubuntu1804/versions/1.0.4/providers/virtualbox.box box seems to work better.

I tried using this official xenial64 box and it worked like a charm.

https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/xenial64/versions/20190507.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box

Give a try with these image.